# Как сделать поиск по Json и вытянуть данные по условию

Tags: javascript, php, json

Как реализовать поиск по JSON на другом домене средствами PHP данные по matchid к примеру 61850081496580?

Код JSON :

```
{
    "MatchList": [{
        "id": "0",
        "matchid": "61850081496580",
        "live": true,
        "type": "football",
        "date": "01-24-19",
        "dateString": "09:31",
        "title": "Paro - Transport ",
        "titleseo": "paro-transport",
        "embed": "https://www.yoursite.com",
        "FrameLink": "https://www.boostreaming.ooo/live/paro-transport"
    }, {
        "id": "1",
        "matchid": "95219091403183065231",
        "live": true,
        "type": "tennis",
        "date": "01-24-19",
        "dateString": "11:15",
        "title": "Sebastian  - Marc Polma",
        "titleseo": "sebastian-marc-polma",
        "embed": "https://www.yoursite.com",
        "FrameLink": "https://www.boostreaming.ooo/live/sebastian-marc-polma"
    },  {
        "id": "3",
        "matchid": "314935035807952144906",
        "live": true,
        "type": "tennis",
        "date": "01-24-19",
        "dateString": "11:30",
        "title": "Maxime Mor - Giovanni F",
        "titleseo": "maxime-mor-giovanni-f",
        "embed": "https://www.yoursite.com",
        "FrameLink": "https://www.boostreaming.ooo/live/maxime-mor-giovanni-f"
    },  {
        "id": "6",
        "matchid": "556695890309283941065",
        "live": true,
        "type": "tennis",
        "date": "01-24-19",
        "dateString": "11:45",
        "title": "Zeppieri/M - Svrcina/Fo",
        "titleseo": "zeppieri-m-svrcina-fo",
        "embed": "https://www.yoursite.com",
        "FrameLink": "https://www.boostreaming.ooo/live/zeppieri-m-svrcina-fo"
    }, ],
    "Statue": true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = FALSE [, resource $context [, int $offset = 0 [, int $maxlen ]]]] ) : string
json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = FALSE [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] ) : mixed
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: А причем здесь file_get_contents?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Я то читал первую ревизию вопроса, и там была еще вот эта ссылка `test.test?jsontest.json` как я понял из контекста это ссылка на "другой домен" где лежит JSON, поэтому file_get_contents чтобы получть данные =)